# PaperScript : Why for non pre-defined shapes, it is need to be selected for it to display?

Tags: javascript, html, paperjs

I am new to PaperScript and I am trying to make hexagon using it. I have used following two codes. One works and one doesn't. I am not able to figure out the reason behind this behaviour:

Working code:

```
var triangle = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(80, 70), 3, 50);
triangle.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
triangle.selected = true;
```

Not working code:

```
var triangle = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(80, 70), 3, 50);
triangle.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
```

Why there is need to select the path for it to display (in case of not pre defined shapes) but for pre-defined shapes (like Circle or Rectangle) it is not needed?

Comment: Your second code works fine: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfHLEosUSooyE/PSc1IVbBXyUssVAhJLMvSCUtNLcxKLAvJzKtPz8zTA4vmZeSUaFgY6CuYGmjoKxjoKpgaa1jF5MO16aZk5Oc75OflFQIPUlVMtUy3T0tStgXYlFaUmZheAtBcrWUXH1gIA is the color maybe to light for your screen?

Comment: call `view.update()` after you define your shape